# Extract statistics from IIS log

Tags: iis, logging

Is there a simple way to find the number of calls to a specific page from the IIS log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `find /c "/url/to/page" <logfilename>`. It's cheap and simple but might just do what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Using Microsoft's [IIS LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en):

```
LogParser -o:w3c "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Requests] FROM {filename}
WHERE cs-uri-query = '{requestUrl}'
```

*(all in one line)*